# How can i turn mobile data on without going into the settings?

Tags: settings, cellular-data

I have recently purchased an Iphone 5s, when i turn the mobile data on and off i have to go into the settings. Is there any way i can do it easier? I have tried flicking up from the top and bottom, however cannot find an easier way.

Answer (score -1):

There is no specific way to turn off only Cellular Data without going into settings.  A (possibly) quicker work around for you would be swiping up from the bottom to get the control center, then turning on Airplane Mode (far left button) and then turning back on WiFi and/or bluetooth.

That would disable cellular data,WiFi, Bluetooth by going into Airplane Mode, and you would get data over WiFi back when you turn that back on.

Comment: I would argue this is a very bad idea for a big reason. This eliminates any ability to use the non-data part of cellular network for non-data reasons such as phone calls, SMS messages, or GPS information.

Comment: I agree, it's not ideal, but it does accomplish his goal.  There are just side affects.

Comment: Yes, but since turning off cellular data is easy in settings, creating an answer that harder and has massive side affects while touting it as a "shortcut" isn't the way I would go. I would simply answer the question as "No, there is no easier way to do it"

Answer (score -1):

Try the launcher app. It works great into the mobile data settings screen directly from the Today swipe down screen.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Could you [edit] your answer to provide at least a link to the app, and maybe some screenshots showing how it works? As it stands, this is a low-quality answer and may be deleted.